# ExtJs:Search Filter in combo box

Tags: extjs4

I have a combo box with list a set of values,

```
Ext.define('loincList', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{ name: 'loincNumber', mapping: 'loincNumber' },
                     { name: 'component', mapping: 'component' }            
            ]
        });    

ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'loincList',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : url+'/lochweb/loch/LOINCData/getLOINCData',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'LOINCData'
                }
            }
        });
```

combo box:

```
{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Search Loinc Code',
        name: "loincId",       
        displayField: 'loincNumber',                    
        valueField: 'id',
        width: 400,                 
        store: ds,
        queryMode: 'local',
        allowBlank:false,
        listConfig: {
            getInnerTpl: function() {
                return '<div data-qtip="{loincNumber}.{component}">{loincNumber} {component} {status}</div>';
            }
        }

    }
```

when i type a number in the combo-box it filter based on the number entered but when i type a text ,it is not filtering based on text entered.**How to filter based on text entered.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type the data to the combobox, it will filter based on the `displayField`. So I think when you "type a text it is not filtering based on text entered" because no items in the combo has `displayField` with prefix like the text you typed.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is working on server side, if you will switch on something like Firebug, you will see special param (usually named filter) with text you typed in control, So you need to check what happen on your server-side. You need to handle with filter text and make filters as you want on server-side.

Comment: No,it is not server side filtering.It is Extjs combo box that provides filtering facilitiy i hope.